# How is this called, and what do I need to do to get it in Neovim?

Tags: neovim

Honestly I don't even know where to ask this, but I want to get a plugin in order to get this inside my nvim, but I don't even know what it is called to search for it

So, what do you call the thing on the right, the one that shows an error? (this is a screenshot from KDevelop)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I believe NeoVim calls this "virtual text"; it appears to come from a linter/compiler/LSP/etc.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thanks! Do you know how I could get it into my configuration?

Comment: There are several plugins that connect Vim to a LSP server. [Coc.nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim)  is one.

Comment: NeoVim has a builtin LSP support, I believe

Comment: I got it working now, and I made a minimal configuration for everyone to use

Comment: @Andy3153 I've rolled back your edit; edits are not for answers to the question. Please post an answer below if you have a solution, and include any necessary code directly.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Okay, I will do that. But, in case I change the code where I maintain it, is it fine to place a link to where the code will possibly be more up to date?

Comment: @Andy3153 yea that’s totally fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually got it working now, and, because I really wanted this when I was trying to get it working, here is a minimal working `init.lua` configuration file to get it up and running, for anyone else that might need it.

Due to the current way I configured it for now, it'll quit once by itself, then you should **re-run it three times**. Why?

- Once, so that `plug.vim` installs the plugins needed
- A second time, so that `nvim-lsp-installer` installs the LSP servers (check installation progress by using `:LspInstallInfo`)
- And then, if you run it a third time, the LSP servers will load

I am extremely open to suggestions for this, I know the plugin automation and `plug.vim` bootstrapping is basically held together by electrical tape, if there's anyone who knows how to do any of this better, please inform me.

For a potentially more up-to-date version of this config, [click here](https://gitlab.com/Andy3153/nvim-minimal_inline_lsp_config).

```lua
-- vim:fileencoding=utf-8:foldmethod=marker
--
-- Minimal working configuration to get working inline errors/LSP virtual text in Neovim
-- by Andy3153
--

-- Add here all the LSPs you want, see :LspInstallInfo or github.com/williamboman/nvim-lsp-installer#available-lsps
lspservers_to_install =
{
  -- Examples:
  'clangd',     -- C/C++
  'pylsp',      -- Python
  'sumneko_lua' -- Lua
}

-- {{{ Setting the environment up
vim.fn.setenv("NVIM_DATA_FOLDER", vim.fn.stdpath('data'))
vim.fn.setenv("AUTOLOAD_FOLDER",  vim.fn.getenv('NVIM_DATA_FOLDER') .. "/site/autoload/")
vim.fn.setenv("PLUG_FOLDER",      vim.fn.getenv('AUTOLOAD_FOLDER')  .. "/plugged/")

-- {{{ Installing plugins
-- Feel free to do this however you please, with whatever package manager you like
vim.cmd [[
  " Bootstraps plug.vim
  if empty(glob('$AUTOLOAD_FOLDER/plug.vim'))
    silent !curl -fLo $AUTOLOAD_FOLDER/plug.vim --create-dirs
      \ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
    silent !touch $AUTOLOAD_FOLDER/.setup-needed
    autocmd VimEnter * q
  endif

  " Plugin list
  call plug#begin('$PLUG_FOLDER')
    Plug 'neovim/nvim-lspconfig'
    Plug 'williamboman/nvim-lsp-installer'
  call plug#end()

  " Installs plugins after plug.vim was downloaded
  if empty(glob('$AUTOLOAD_FOLDER/.setup-needed'))
  else
    autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall
    silent !rm $AUTOLOAD_FOLDER/.setup-needed
  endif
]]
-- }}}
-- }}}

-- {{{ Setting up plugins
require("nvim-lsp-installer").setup({ ensure_installed = lspservers_to_install })

-- Forloop that enables all LSPs mentioned in the lspservers_to_install array
for _, lsp in ipairs(lspservers_to_install) do
  require('lspconfig')[lsp].setup{sdf="sdf"} -- don't even ask me why anything is required in there, it won't work without it
end
-- }}}
```

EDIT: How does it look? Not good, it's a barebones config. Here's some code with mistakes in it to showcase it:

[image]

Comment: RE: duct tape, downloading a file into autoload doesn't require a restart if all you do is call it's autoload functions; it will be found by the autoload mechanism. So that can be removed. For installing the servers, that should be something you only need to do occasionally, so I would recommend dropping the auto-`:PlugInstall` and either run it as needed interactively or from the command-line with `+PlugInstall`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble If I remove the quitting (ln.29: `"autocmd VimEnter * q`), on first launch, nvim is going to complain about it: `Vim(call):E117: Unknown function: plug#begin`. Also, `:PlugInstall` gets ran only once, when downloading `plug.vim`, it creates a file. If that file exists, it runs `PlugInstall` and then deletes the file.

And, the LSP servers only get installed once (when on ln.49, `nvim-lsp-installer` is being told that it has to make sure that all the LSPs inside the `lspservers_to_install` array are installed), not everytime nvim starts.

Comment: The error surprises me; that’s not how autoload is supposed to work. It should search for the autoload file when the function is first called.

Comment: Wait, what autoload function?

Comment: `plug#begin` is autoloaded from the plug.vim that you download

Comment: Yes, but it needs a restart to autoload it then, apparently. Or there might be some command needed. Or something to reload nvim without restarting it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136051/discussion-between-d-ben-knoble-and-andy3153).